# Aspectj around advice for field and class initializaton

Tags: java, aspectj

Im implementing kind-of monitoring framework for my application. Basic idea is to use Aspectj to weave a piece of code that exposes variable anotated with certain annotation via JMX.
So i use pointcut

```
@Around("get (@mypackage.Gauge * *) && @annotation(annotation)")
```

However, in order to get my variable exposed via JMX i need to get it's value once (so that JMX binding occur). I use compile-time weaving. Is there any way that i can execute a certain piece of code once the class with @Gauge annotation is loaded?

Comment: The question is unclear, please elaborate. Why should CTW vs LTW make any difference here? No matter when and how aspect code is woven, it will always be executed during runtime.

Comment: Runing app with spring assume your beans are created via declaration in .xml file. In that case i can add InitializingBean interface to those classes and perform initialization in afterPropertiesSet method. However, my beans are not created directly by spring, so i can't use InitializingBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way that i can execute a certain piece of code once the
>   class with `@Gauge` annotation is loaded?

Yes. Try this:

```java
after() : staticinitialization(@Gauge *) {
    // Do something here
}
```